# RegisterAutoWired: analog for Unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, servicestack, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am currently converting a project that uses ServiceStack's DI to Unity. I am currently stuck at ServiceStack's RegisterAutoWired method that registers a concrete class.

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<MyClass>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

What method in IUnityContainer should I use to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IUnityContainer.RegisterType<MyClass, MyClass>();`

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to register concrete classes.  Unity will new up a concrete class for you (but it defaults to picking the constructor with the most parameters).  If you need to specify a specific constructor or if you need to set up a special lifetime, then you may want to register it.

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<MyClass>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), // Singleton
    new InjectionConstructor(myConstructorParameter1, ...);
```

Or if you have a complex scenario where you need to control how the type is instantiated, you can use `RegisterInstance` or an `InjectionFactory`.

```
var myClassInstance = new MyClass();
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(myClassInstance);

unityContainer.RegisterType<MyClass>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => new MyClass()));
```

The [Developer's Guide to Dependency Injection Using Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx) is very helpful.